# Weird Entity Framework .Include() behavior

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6

I was surprised to see that the following code did not really include `TheLinkedThing`:

```
await db.Set<TheThing>()
                    .Include(e => e.TheLinkedThing)
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == someId);
```

I can see that in SQL Profiler, no `join` operator is generated. However, the following query works as expected:

```
await db.Set<TheThing>()
                    .Where(e => e.Id == someId)
                    .Include(e => e.TheLinkedThing)
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Why does that happen? I can't find anything in the documentation that would explain it as expected behavior. I use the latest 6.1.3 version, lazy loading is disabled.

Comment: Weird behavior indeed. I just tried to reproduce it but failed. The profiler shows that a INNER JOIN is created.